# How to load angular website home page faster without dynamic loading controller concept

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have used lots of js using the Angular framework. I have a big project and in index page I load all required files with bundle concept of MVC. Everything works fine, but Index page takes a long time to get loaded.

I know the concept of dynamic loading AngularJs controller, but this seems impossible to go with that idea as we have a massive project running live. We can't change whole architecture now.

So is there any other way or workaround to get it resolved?

Comment: Can you describe the load process better. For instance how much of it is download time and how much is setup time.

Comment: it takes lots of time. around 2 to 3 min... in mobile it takes a lot.

Comment: you can check out business.bookmyfood.co.in

Comment: I want to make it faster than it is.

Comment: What about starting to bundle all the scripts?

Comment: all files added through bundle.